# Melhor prática para dados apagados

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estou na dúvida de qual a melhor forma para lidar com dados excluídos. No sistema deve aparecer para o cliente a opção, "excluir dado", mas o fato que a exclusão desse dado teria que apagar diversos outros dados que são relacionados a ele e também afetaria uma outra ponta de outro cliente que faz relacionamento com esses dados.

O que devo fazer? Manter uma tag colocando o status desse dado como "lixeira" e mostrar para o cliente como se tivesse sido apagado, mas mantendo na base dados?

Comment: Recentemente tive algumas experiências ruins por não termos uma `Lixeira`. Recomendo incluir uma coluna na tabela que diz se o dado pode ou não ser exibido. Mas deletar jamais, usuários e até nós mesmo programadores estamos sujeito a erros.

Comment: Você quer que um mesmo registro conste como excluído para um usuário, e como não-excluído para outro? Aí é mais complicado do que ter simplesmente um status de deletado.

Comment: @bfavaretto exato. Pois se trata de um marketplace, se um usuário se excluir o outro cliente que já teve um 'relacionamento' com ele, ficará sem referência ao dado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma técnica que desenvolvi e não é nenhuma novidade, é mover os dados para uma outra tabela.

Normalmente duplico quase todas as tabelas e para algumas crio ainda uma terceira tabela auxiliar.

Exemplo, uma tabela de opções de um produto

```
item_option
item_option_deleted
item_option_archived
```

Na tabela item_option, estão os dados originais. Quando uma ação de exclusão é realizada, o usuário tem opção de **mover para lixeira** ou **excluir definitivamente**.

Quando **move para a lixeira**, os dados vão para `item_option_deleted` e quando **exclui em definitivo** vão para `item_option_archived`.

Tudo que está em `*_archived` não é recuperável pela interface do usuário comum.

Ou seja, virtualmente, para o usuário, existe um recovery somente para os dados que estão em `*_deleted`, mas para o administrador o acesso é liberado as tabelas `*_archived` também.

Mas não se trata apenas de exclusão acidental ou no caso do usuário se arrepender. Conforme mencionou na pergunta, uma complicação são os **relacionamentos existentes**.

Numa loja virtual, por exemplo, um cliente compra um produto com opção A e B. Após 1 semana a loja resolve excluir essas opções em definitivo. Então o que acontece com o histórico desses clientes que compraram com essas opções que estão deletadas?

Aí entra o suporte da tabela `item_option_archived`. No histórico de compras do cliente tem a referência para as opções A e B mas não estão presentes na tabela `item_option`. Nesse caso, é feito uma busca nas tabelas `item_option_deleted` e `item_option_archived`.

Para evitar ter quase o triplo de tabelas no banco, já experimentei colocar essas tabelas numa outra base dados mas o gerenciamento de uma segunda base torna-se mais complexo e em casos onde o provedor de hospedagem não permite mais que 1 base de dados, o sistema obviamente não funcionará. Por isso, preferi simplificar tudo numa mesma base.

## Por quê não criar uma flag?

Isso é uma escolha que depende do caso. Eu prefiro manter um padrão movendo os dados para outras tabelas conforme descrito acima pois a tabela original vai ficando pesada com tantos dados com status de "excluído" ou "excluído em definitivo". É muito comum uma loja pequena excluir produtos em definitivo e em pouco tempo ter uma tabela com 50 mil produtos, sendo que somente 1200 são válidos. O restante é tudo lixo que já foi excluído.
Isso afeta na performance, numa busca ou num simples `SELECT`. É obviamente mais rápido procurar dentro de 1200 registros do que em 50 mil.

Saliento que não é errado usar a técnica da flag pois cada caso é um caso. Há casos onde é mais conveniente apenas criar uma flag.

Comment: não seria mais barato manter um indice que consultar duas tabelas?

Comment: A consulta as tabelas auxiliares _deleted e _archived são baixas. As consultas são mais frequentes na tabela original. Considerando custo benefício e eficiência, é uma forma melhor do que a técnica com flag, na maioria dos casos com os quais eu costumo lidar.

Comment: Qual o Banco de Dados que você costuma utilizar?

Comment: Isso é indiferente, mas uso MySQL

Comment: Daniel, apenas uma sugestão, como o `item_option_deleted` estará presente em todas as suas consultas, você poderia fazer uso do particionamento da tabela, em MySQL é feito da seguinte forma.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html. você teria o arranjo fisico semelhante ao da sua abordagem, porem a aplicação poderia abstrair isto completamente.

Comment: Normalmente o _deleted e _archived não estão presentes nas consultas. Isso só se faz necessário quando precisa consultar algum relacionamento e este for inexistente na tabela principal. O partitioning conheço, mas sempre evito usar recursos específicos de um SGDB pois posso precisar mudar de SGDB e isso dá um certo trabalho, especialmente se o outro ambiente não tem recurso similar.

Answer (score 6):

Como orientações gerais de boas práticas de armazenamento, sempre é interessante armazenar os registros quando "apagados" e criar uma *flag* para eles fazendo a indicação de deleção, porém algumas perguntas devem ser respondidas:

- Qual a frequência de restauração desses dados?
- Eles tem algum outro propósito (monitoria...)?
- Eles podem ser transformados parcialmente para outra tabela?

Por experiência própria eu prefiro manter esses dados, mas para alguns casos eu uso [tabelas temporárias](http://talentedmonkeys.wordpress.com/2010/05/15/temporal-data-in-a-relational-database/), o que pode te ajudar. Em alguns casos realmente não faz sentido, como por exemplo quando é feito o armazenamento de sessão.

Como citado por ti, a deleção desse dado afetaria outros relacionamentos, mas nesse caso note que se você oferece a deleção ao usuário este problema deveria ser tratado na modelagem da sua tabela.

Logo a resposta final é: Depende.

[Fonte](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159232/should-we-ever-delete-data-in-a-database)